# how to sum two columns of non-zero values

Tags: r

my data looks like this

```
df<- structure(list(team_3_F = c("browingal ", "team ", "browingal ", 
"browingal ", "team ", "browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", 
"browingal ", "newyorkish", "newyorkish", "site", "site", "browingal ", 
"browingal ", "site", "site", "team ", "team ", "team ", "site", 
"site", "browingal ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", 
"team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", 
"team ", "team ", "newyorkish", "newyorkish", "team ", "team ", 
"team ", "browingal ", "browingal "), AAA_US = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 88L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 45L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 0L, 0L), BBB_US = c(0L, 0L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 45L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-44L))
```

I want to sum those rows that both columns have non-zero values , so the output should look like this

```
df<- structure(list(team_3_F = c("browingal ", "team ", "browingal ", 
"browingal ", "team ", "browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", 
"browingal ", "newyorkish", "newyorkish", "site", "site", "browingal ", 
"browingal ", "site", "site", "team ", "team ", "team ", "site", 
"site", "browingal ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", 
"team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", 
"team ", "team ", "newyorkish", "newyorkish", "team ", "team ", 
"team ", "browingal ", "browingal "), AAA_US = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 88L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 45L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 0L, 0L), BBB_US = c(0L, 0L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 45L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 1L, 0L), NEW = c(0L, 0L, 
3L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 47L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 38L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-44L))
```

I have tried to sum with various version of the following but I could not figure how to fix it

```
df$new <- rowSums(df[ , c(2,3)], na.rm=FALSE)
df$new <- rowSums(df[ , c(2,3)], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can multiply the `rowSums` output with a logical vector that only becomes TRUE when all the elements in the same row are not 0 (create the logical vector with `rowSums` on a logical matrix (`df[, 2:3] != 0`)

```
df$new <- rowSums(df[, 2:3]) * (rowSums(df[, 2:3] != 0) == 2)
```

-testing

```
> all.equal(df$new, out$NEW)
[1] TRUE
```

-output

```
> df
     team_3_F AAA_US BBB_US new
1  browingal       0      0   0
2       team       0      0   0
3  browingal       1      2   3
4  browingal       0      3   0
5       team       1      4   5
6  browingal       0      2   0
7  browingal       0      1   0
8  browingal       0      0   0
9  browingal       1      1   2
10 newyorkish     88      0   0
11 newyorkish      5      3   8
12       site      0      8   0
13       site      0      0   0
14 browingal       0      0   0
15 browingal       0      0   0
16       site      0      0   0
17       site     45      0   0
18      team       0      0   0
19      team       0      0   0
20      team       1      1   2
21       site      0      0   0
22       site      0      0   0
23 browingal       0      2   0
24      team       0      0   0
25      team       0      0   0
26      team       0      0   0
27      team       0      0   0
28      team       2     45  47
29      team       0      0   0
30      team       0      0   0
31      team       0      0   0
32      team       0     18   0
33      team       0      0   0
34      team       0      0   0
35      team       0      0   0
36      team       0      1   0
37      team       0      0   0
38 newyorkish     11      0   0
39 newyorkish      1      0   0
40      team       0      0   0
41      team       0      0   0
42      team      19     19  38
43 browingal       0      1   0
44 browingal       0      0   0
```

NOTE: Here, `out` is the expected output - renamed as both the input and output are named with same object `df`

---

Or if there are only two columns, an option can be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(new = case_when(AAA_US != 0 & BBB_US != 0 ~
       AAA_US + BBB_US, TRUE ~ 0L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible base R option, which will work if you have additional columns to consider. First, I return a logical using `df[,-1] != 0` to determine whether a value is not 0, then I use `rowSums` to get the total of `TRUE` values. Then, if the number of non-zero values equals the number of columns (excluding the `team_3_F` column) (i.e., `== ncol(df[,-1]`), then we can get the sum of that row, and if not, then return 0.

```
df$NEW <- ifelse(rowSums(df[,-1] != 0) == ncol(df[,-1]), rowSums(df[,-1]), 0)
```

**Testing**

```
all.equal(df_expected$NEW, df$NEW)
#[1] TRUE
```

**Output**

```
     team_3_F AAA_US BBB_US NEW
1  browingal       0      0   0
2       team       0      0   0
3  browingal       1      2   3
4  browingal       0      3   0
5       team       1      4   5
6  browingal       0      2   0
7  browingal       0      1   0
8  browingal       0      0   0
9  browingal       1      1   2
10 newyorkish     88      0   0
11 newyorkish      5      3   8
12       site      0      8   0
13       site      0      0   0
14 browingal       0      0   0
15 browingal       0      0   0
16       site      0      0   0
17       site     45      0   0
18      team       0      0   0
19      team       0      0   0
20      team       1      1   2
21       site      0      0   0
22       site      0      0   0
23 browingal       0      2   0
24      team       0      0   0
25      team       0      0   0
26      team       0      0   0
27      team       0      0   0
28      team       2     45  47
29      team       0      0   0
30      team       0      0   0
31      team       0      0   0
32      team       0     18   0
33      team       0      0   0
34      team       0      0   0
35      team       0      0   0
36      team       0      1   0
37      team       0      0   0
38 newyorkish     11      0   0
39 newyorkish      1      0   0
40      team       0      0   0
41      team       0      0   0
42      team      19     19  38
43 browingal       0      1   0
44 browingal       0      0   0
```